# I want the note middle-C to be denoted in bass clef in GarageBand

Tags: sheet-music, garage-band

I'm trying to generate a PDF of music sheet with GarageBand, but there's a problem.

Even though I play an arpeggio F-A-C-E-G, the note C3 (middle-C) is denoted in treble clef.<sup>1</sup> Even if I moved it down to bass clef one by one, it somehow goes back to treble clef.

[image: Score on a grand staff, with a middle-C note denoted in treble clef.]

Do you have any idea to solve this? More concretely, I want all the notes at or lower than C3 to be denoted in bass clef.

---

<sup>1.</sup> In GarageBand, middle C is denoted C3 rather than the standard C4.

Comment: No can do in 2012, maybe the same today https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4551071   You'll have to use an actual score writing program.

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica Seems like an answer!

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica OMG, what a tragedy. Thank you :)

Comment: If you haven’t tried Musescore yet for making sheet music, you should. It’s free.